# C# Hashtable searching

Tags: c#, search, hashtable

I need to make a search in some data. First of all, my code selects the 29th digit and keep 4 digits of it(it is 1721 in the below as you can see), and it compares the lines below. I managed to search 29th 4 digit and showing message as you can see if there is the searched number in the lines, that was easy part. Here is my question; how can make it show first 4 digits, second 3 digits, third 6 digits fourth 6 digits on labels(label9, label10, label11, label12) when I search the number. I tried to `currentLine.Substring(1, 4);` but it showed an error:

> substring is null.

Do i need a loop in //search if part?

For example, assume that we put 1723 on search, it must show 1097 on label9, it must show 003 on label10, and etc.

The data:

```
1096:001:161207:085050:1721:001:F:000:0007       
1096:001:161207:085050:1721:001:F:000:0007           
1099:003:161207:085719:1722:001:F:000:0007       
1099:003:161207:085719:1722:001:F:000:0007      
1097:002:161207:085719:1723:001:F:000:0007       
1097:002:161207:085719:1723:001:F:000:0007
```

Codes:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    String currentItemIndex = "", currentItemData = "", currentLine = "";
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Select File
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        textBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        //Select File

        //Read And Split
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName.ToString());
        StreamReader read = file.OpenText();

        currentLine = read.ReadLine();
        currentItemIndex = currentLine.Substring(23, 4);
        currentItemData += currentLine;
        do
        {
            currentLine = read.ReadLine();
            if (currentLine == null)
            {
                hashtable.Add(currentItemIndex, currentItemData);
                break;
            }

            if (!currentItemIndex.Equals(currentLine.Substring(23, 4)))
            {
                hashtable.Add(currentItemIndex, currentItemData);
                currentItemData = "";
                currentItemIndex = currentLine.Substring(23, 4);
            }


            currentItemData += currentLine;
        } while (true);
    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Search Start
        string search = textBox2.Text;
        if (hashtable.ContainsKey(search))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Found");
            label9.Text=
            label10.Text=
            label11.Text=
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NotFound"); }
            //Search End
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, is there any reason you're using `Hashtable` rather than `Dictionary<,>`? The non-generic collections have been somewhat-obsolete-for-new-code since 2005...

Comment: You would probably be better off splitting the string into an array of values based on the `:`.

Comment: Actually i don't know how to use `Dictionary`

Comment: Well he might need hashtable if he got lots of data, dictionaries are a bit slower and you also have to be sure that all dictionary keys are unique in your data. But he might consider looking into dictionaries here a starters link : https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here is for curious people:

```
        string search = textBox2.Text;
        if (hashtable.ContainsKey(search))

        {

            this.Size = new Size(324, 260);


            string value1 = (string)hashtable[search];
            label9.Text= value1.Substring(0, 4);
            label10.Text = value1.Substring(5, 3);
            label11.Text = value1.Substring(9, 6);
            label12.Text = value1.Substring(16, 6);
            label13.Text = value1.Substring(23, 4);
            MessageBox.Show("Found");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NotFound");

        }
```